# How to set Image on Gallery through XML parse in Android?

Tags: android, android-xml, android-gallery

I can set Image on ListVew through XML parse but I can't set image on Gallery. Please let me know how to do that and any links to tutorials or sample could would help.

Answer (score 2):

This question has not a specific answer. You have to use many things. You just search on Gallery view and Lazy adapter...

Answer (score 1):

By using the XML parsing, parse all the image url's. After getting all the image url's you can load the images using [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview). On the LazyLoading code they have used a ListView in the layout so the images and the corresponding text are shown as list items, you can change that ListView to a Gallery something like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <Gallery android:id="@+id/gallery" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:text="Clear Cache"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

I think this will get you the desired result.

Comment: @user818992 if my answer helped you on solving your issue, then kindly accept my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation